# How to hashify the URL after the ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, url, twitter

What I know that `window.location.hash = hash_url`  is used to hashify the URL. Suppose I am at `http://www.example.com` And I want to hashify it. `window.location.hash = #foo` will lead to the URL `http://example.com/#foo` But what about when My actual URL is 
`http://example.com/bar` But after hasifying I want it to `http://example.com/#foo` not like `http://example.com/bar/#foo`.
How twitter hashify works?

Comment: Its html5 manipulating the url address bar, something about its location history... i'll see if I can find something for you

Comment: @Val: No; Twitter is using normal hashes.

Comment: I was saying there is another thing you could use I have not checked what twitter uses for it ... look at my answer you will understand what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all You lot can be wrong :)

http://html5demos.com/history/

secondly The only thing im not sure about is cross browser compatable,

last but not least why would it matter whether the bar is there or not ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change the non-hash portion of the URL without reloading the page.

Twitter works by sending an HTTP redirect from `twitter.com/X` to `twitter.com/#!/X`.

Comment: But I think for a HTTP request whole page reloads but With twitter only some div reloads ..

Comment: @user: After than initial redirect, the full location never changes, and it uses hashes instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are at `http://example.com/bar` and want to go to `http://example.com/#foo` you must use `window.location  = 'http://example.com/#foo'`, because with `hash` you can only change the hash of your URL, not the path.